# How to save a fitz.Page as bytes (later to be uploaded to azure blob)?

Tags: python, pdf, stream, azure-blob-storage, pymupdf

I have a `fitz.fitz.Page` object that I wanted to save as `bytes` that I later want to upload to blob storage and have been unable to find out this in the fitz documentation

I do have the code to upload bytes to the blob storage though and just need help on the function `store_fitz_page_as_bytes()`

Mind you, I am not speaking about saving `fitz.fitz.Document` object as bytes.. that's already known to me (by using the save method).
I basically want to store each page in `fitz.fitz.Document` (each page will be of type `fitz.fitz.Page`) as bytes.

```
import fitz


def store_fitz_page_as_bytes(fitz_page: fitz.fitz.Page)->bytes:
    '''
    need help here to convert fitz_page to bytes and return it. 
    -This needs to be done without any local storage
    -fitz_page.select([0]) is not an option for me as I need to do this for all pages
    '''

def upload_bytes_to_azure_blob(pdf_bytes):
    '''
    I already know this so don't really want to derail the conversation to this subject. Just mentioning this so that the forum knows my purpose
    '''

#read a 200 page pdf as fitz.fitz.Document
fitz_doc = fitz.open("test.pdf")
print(type(fitz_doc))

#just get the first item from fitz_doc. It will be the first page from the 200 page pdf and will be of type fitz.fitz.Page
fitz_page = fitz_doc[0]
print(type(fitz_page))

#convert fitz_page from above to bytes
pdf_bytes = store_fitz_page_as_bytes(fitz_page)

#upload bytes to blob
upload_bytes_to_azure_blob(pdf_bytes)
```

Comment: @KJ Yes I managed to solve it similarly using 2 `fitz.Document` objects instead of trying to so save `fitz.page` as bytes.. `Object#1` is the full pdf and `Object #2` is initialized as empty.. Then I use `Object#2.insert_pdf()` to insert just a single from `Object#1` into `Object#2`. For saving `Object#2` as bytes, I used `Object#2.save()` ..    I took guidance from https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/issues/880

Answer (score 0):

> Want to store each page in `fitz.fitz.Document` (each page will be of type `fitz.fitz.Page`) as bytes.

You can use the below code to convert each page in the PDF document to bytes and upload them to Azure Blob Storage as separate PDF files.

**Code:**

```
import fitz
from io import BytesIO
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

def store_fitz_page_as_bytes(fitz_page: fitz.Page) -> bytes:
    # Render the page as a PNG image
    pix = fitz_page.get_pixmap(alpha=False)
    image_data = pix.tobytes()

    # Encode the image data as bytes
    stream = BytesIO()
    stream.write(image_data)
    stream.seek(0)
    return stream.read()

def upload_bytes_to_azure_blob(pdf_bytes, blob_name):
    connection_string = "Your-connection-string"
    container_name = "test1"
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)

    container_client.upload_blob(name=blob_name, data=pdf_bytes, overwrite=True)
fitz_doc = fitz.open("test890.pdf") #(It has 6 pages)

for page_number, page in enumerate(fitz_doc):
    pdf_bytes = store_fitz_page_as_bytes(page)
    blob_name = f"page_{page_number+1}.pdf"
    upload_bytes_to_azure_blob(pdf_bytes, blob_name)
```

Using the connection string and container name supplied, the **`upload_bytes_to_azure_blob`** function executes uploading the bytes to Azure Blob Storage.

The **`store_fitz_page_as_bytes`** function is used in the for loop to run over each page of the PDF document (fitz_doc) and convert each page to bytes. Then, you upload the bytes for each page to Azure Blob Storage along with a separate blob name which includes the page number.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: if you do that, will you have the page as an image but not a fitz page object?